# Cant use subscribeon() & observeon() RxJava2/RxAndroid2 in android

Tags: android

I am using Rxjava/RxAndroid2 for that i have implemented

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
```

but i cannot use the method of SubscribeOn() & obseveOn().Please tell me where is the problem.I am using android studio 3.1.3

```
private void getMenu() {

        compositeDisposable.add(mService.getMenu().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Category>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(List<Category> categories) throws Exception {
                displayMenu(categories);
            }
        }));
    }
```

Error shows cannot resolve method subscribeOn(io.reactivex.Scheduler)
[image]

Comment: please post the problematic code so that we can tailor feedback to your problem

Comment: private void getMenu() {

        compositeDisposable.add(mService.getMenu().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Category>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(List<Category> categories) throws Exception {
                displayMenu(categories);
            }
        }));
    }  error shows canot resolve subscribeon(io.reactivex.sceduler)

Comment: what is the return type for `mService.getMenu()`?

Comment: in return i am displaying list of images

Comment: mService.getBanners() return an Observable?